# C# error Win32Exception was unhandled - Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation, win32exception

I am attempting to launch a .exe file using different user credentials.  It keeps returning an "unknown user name or bad password" error but I have verified that these are correct. Is there any way to debug this further or anything wrong with my code?

---

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System;
//using System.ComponentModel;
//using System.IO;

namespace MTEK_856_as_Admin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            password.AppendChar('p');
            password.AppendChar('a');
            password.AppendChar('s');
            password.AppendChar('s');

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\\\htohna02\\ERP\\EDIData\\";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "MTEK_856.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Domain = "am.mds.xxxxx.com/AMU";
            process.StartInfo.UserName = @"Admin";
            process.StartInfo.Password = password;
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```